# How ";" can be unexpected token? (React/Babel)

Tags: javascript, api, reactjs

I am learning on how make API with Node.js and React, from this source code:
[link](https://github.com/iamshaunjp/rest-api-playlist/blob/lesson-16/public/index.html)

```
         getLangData: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var lang = this.refs.lang.value;
    
            fetch("/api/getLangData?lang="+lang)
            .then(function(data) {
                return data.json();
            })
            .then(json => {
                this.SetState({
                    langData: json
                })
            })
        }
```

And I have the next error:

```
SyntaxError: http://localhost:3000/js/api.js: Unexpected token (28:26)
  26 |     },
  27 |     getLangData: function(e) {
> 28 |         e.preventDefault();
     |                           ^
  29 |         var lang = this.refs.lang.value;
  30 | 
  31 |         fetch("/api/getLangData?lang="+lang)
```

How ";" can be unexpected token? What's wrong with my code?

My full code: https://jsfiddle.net/s7xdbrcw/

Comment: Theres probably an unclosed (( before... ( or sth similar)

Comment: @Jonasw I revised my code many times, but I did not find an error ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See line 13 of your fiddle:

```
return (
    <li key={index}>
        {data.obj.data}
    <li/>
)
```

should be

```
return (
    <li key={index}>
        {data.obj.data}
    </li>
)
```

Comment: (By the way, I found this error by running the code through my editor's reindent feature and looking at the line that started to make the code look "odd".)

Comment: Oh my got... Thank you man.